# After merging a branch into main, why does deleting the local branch, then updating the project, not also delete the remote branch?

Tags: git, github

If one makes a commit to the local repository, then pushes the commit, the remote is then updated.  But when deletes a local branch, if one tries to push, Git says there are no changes to push. "Update project" and "Fetch" doesn't delete the remote branch either.  It seems that one must delete the local branch then separately delete the remote branch?  This doesn't seem consistent with the other features of git which sync the local and the remote.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that one must delete the local branch then separately delete the remote branch

Yes.  That's because these are *completely different branches*.  It's a bit like Fred (Frederick Galveston III) vs Fred (Alfred W. Zimblefoord).  While they're both *called* Fred, murdering one of them does not affect the other.

> This doesn't seem consistent with the other features of git which sync the local and the remote.

Which feature(s) are you thinking of here?  If you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

your own `fred` is completely undisturbed; your `origin/fred` may be updated, but that's a completely different fred, again.

If you run:

```
git merge
```

when you're on your `fred` and its upstream is your `origin/fred`, that, of course, updates *your* `fred`, using your `origin/fred`.  But if you choose, say, `origin/wilma` as the upstream for your `origin/fred`, a `git merge` updates from your `origin/wilma`.

If you're thinking of `git pull`, this just runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, such as `git merge`.  If the upstream of `fred` is `origin/wilma`, this once again updates your `fred` from their `wilma` (your `origin/wilma`).

It's really `git push` that is the oddball here: when you run `git push`, you deliver some commits from your Git to their Git, then *ask them to set one of their branch names*.  This part is a bit weird.  You're working with *your* branch, so if this were like `git fetch`, you'd ask them to set a tracking name in *their* repository that they use to keep track of *your* branch.  But instead, you don't ask them to update a tracking name: you ask them to update one of their branches directly.

Comment: Did you just say that `git merge` is a shorthand for `git merge @{u}`? If so I've been wasting a lot of keystrokes! (Me reads docs: "If no commit is given from the command line, merge the remote-tracking branches that the current branch is configured to use as its upstream" Facepalm.)

Comment: @matt: yep:  (there's an emoji for almost everything!)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually three branches in the story:

- local `branch` on your machine
- its tracked remote tracking branch on your machine, eg `origin/branch`
- the remote branch that the remote tracking branch tracks, eg `branch` on GitHub

Each of them is separate and it requires an explicit command to delete each. Some of these can be combined or performed as part of another command, *if you so specify*; but they are three distinct entities, and destroying one automatically *merely* as a consequence of destroying another would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer with a simple example.

> Wouldn't that stink if someone else online pulled your other branch?
>
> you delete it locally, it deletes it remotely.

What happens when everyone else tries to `git push` they will get an error that the remote branch doesn't exist. They would be very confused!

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that in your example, git would just create the branch again without an error?